# how to replay a sound in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Anyone who knows a script on how to replay a sound by clicking a button? My audio automatically plays when a target is detected. And stops when target is lost. Now I need a script on how to replay that sound with a button while still focusing on the same target

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html

Answer (score 0):

Just get a reference to your AudioSource and you can then do audioSource.Play() in your script.

If you want to play multiple audio clips using the same audio source you can get references to your AudioClip and then do audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip) and you should be all good to go.

Comment: sample of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, just drag this script on a GameObject and assign the references to your AudioSource and your Button in the inspector.
You can also remove the Button here from the script and just assign the method `ReplayAudio()` to the onClick events in the button inspector directly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonReplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource AudioSource;
    public Button Button;

    void Start()
    {
        Button.onClick.AddListener(ReplayAudio);
    }

    public void ReplayAudio()
    {
        AudioSource.Play();
    }
}
```